# Unable to remove an event listener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Ok so I have a div with an animation:

```js
var x = true;

function dynamicTaskbar(thumb) {
  function anim1() {
   thumb.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
  function anim2() {
   thumb.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }
  if (x === false) {
   thumb.style.backgroundColor = "red";
   thumb.removeEventListener("mouseover", anim1);
   thumb.removeEventListener("mouseleave", anim2);
      x = true;
  } else {
   thumb.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
   thumb.addEventListener("mouseover", anim1);
   thumb.addEventListener("mouseleave", anim2);
      x = false;
  }
 }

 //Create window's thumbnail for taskbar
 var thumbnail = document.createElement("div");
 thumbnail.setAttribute("class", "thumbnail");
 taskbar.append(thumbnail);
 taskbar.style.width = taskbar.style.width + thumbnail.style.width + "px";
 thumbnail.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
  dynamicTaskbar(thumbnail);
 });
```

```css
#taskbar {
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 1px black;
  
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
}

.thumbnail {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="taskbar"></div>
```

By default, the div is red.

When it is clicked:

- If x is true, it becomes false and the div turns blue. Two event listeners, mouseover (the div becomes green) and mouseleave (the div becomes red again) are added.
- If x is false, it becomes true and the div turns red. But here is my problem: both event listeners (mouseover and mouseleave) are suppose to be removed, but it doesn't work. I searched over the Internet but found nothing that fixed my problem.

Any help?

Comment: Did you try moving the anim1 and anim2 outside the function and see if that helps? I’m not sure but they might be different objects on each call of the parent function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem is extracting the `anim1()` and `anim2()` funtions from the `dynamicTaskbar()` function.

Since both functions are located inside the `dynamicTaskbar()` function they are created again and again with each execution of the function causing the instances to be different then the initial ones.

If for example in the first execution (1st click) of `dynamicTaskbar()` the "object id" of `anim1()` will be "1" and in the second execution it will be "2". Therefore when you're trying to remove the listener you're actually trying to remove it for a different object reference.

Take a look at the example:

```js
var x = true;

function anim1(thumb) {
  thumbnail.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
function anim2(thumb) {
  thumbnail.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
    
function dynamicTaskbar(thumb) {
  if (x === false) {
   thumbnail.style.backgroundColor = "red";
   thumbnail.removeEventListener("mouseover", anim1);
   thumbnail.removeEventListener("mouseleave", anim2);
      x = true;
  } else {
   thumbnail.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
   thumbnail.addEventListener("mouseover", anim1);
   thumbnail.addEventListener("mouseleave", anim2);
      x = false;
  }
 }

 //Create window's thumbnail for taskbar
 var thumbnail = document.createElement("div");
 thumbnail.setAttribute("class", "thumbnail");
 taskbar.append(thumbnail);
 taskbar.style.width = taskbar.style.width + thumbnail.style.width + "px";
 thumbnail.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
  dynamicTaskbar(thumbnail);
 });
```

```css
#taskbar {
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 1px black;
  
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
}

.thumbnail {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="taskbar"></div>
```

Comment: oh... i did not think about that. I will try.